# function wp() does not use meta_query?

Tags: wp-query

I found that the $wp_query variable is populated by wp() function. I would like to filter my results using the WP_Query options.

What I want to do is

```
wp(array("meta_key" => "key", "meta_value" => "value"));
```

Although when I run the following

```
var_dump($wp_query)
```

meta_key and meta_value show up empty.

Any idea how I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `wp()` directly. You should instead use a [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook.